# Angularjs does not recognize "this"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a modal whose contents is generated by an JavaScript method (the reason being that the contents strongly depends on data retrieved from the DB, including hierarchy and its structure).

Initially, I had checkboxes deployed (as part of the generated HTML) as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
       id="Chkbox_1" 
       onClick="Handle_Select(this,1,'Topic_34343')">
```

and, within the javascript (in `Handle_Select`) I could verify if the checkbox was checked or not by testing `this.checked` as follows:

```
Handle_Select = function (p_this,p_Topic_ID, p_Topic_Name) {

   if(p_this.checked) {...}

}
```

Now, I replaced the `onClick` by `ng-click` (as stated, I'm using AngularJS) and suddenly `this` no longer holds the properties of the **input element** but what appears to be the contents of the controller. Of course, the same function now looks:

```
$scope.Handle_Select = function (p_this,p_Topic_ID, p_Topic_Name) {...}
```

Comment: Yes, `ng-click`. Angular directive.

Comment: event handlers typically are passed an event param, if you want to pass other data look at using bind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use this syntax:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
   id="Chkbox_1" 
   ng-click="Handle_Select($event, 1, 'Topic_34343')">
```

Angular code will be:

```
$scope.Handle_Select = function ($event,p_Topic_ID, p_Topic_Name) {
     var target = $event.target;
     if (target.checked) {
         // some code
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @DmitriyLoskutov. Your suggestion works beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

Angular comes with some handy directives that abstract a lot of the typical javascript boilerplate code. In this case, consider using the `ng-model` and `ng-checked` directives. ngModel will bind your input element to a value defined on your scope, and ngChecked will check or uncheck the input depending on a property you define:

```
<input type="checkbox" 
   id="Chkbox_1" 
  ng-model="your_scope_data" ng-checked="your_scope_data.is_checked">
```

so define `$scope.your_scope_data` in your controller, and then angular will tie it together with your template so that the values stay in sync. `your_scope_data.is_checked` is an arbitrary property of the data you bound with `ng-model` to the input element. You can also evaluate a simple expression in `ng-checked` if you want to perform comparisons, etc. Hope this helps, and good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but Dimitriy's is far simpler for me to digest (almost no change to the code).